# How to handle duplicated SVN tags in with git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to clone/migrate an SVN repository with layout like below

```
trunk/
dev-branches/  # branches stored here
branches/      # tags stored here
  some-duplicated-tag
releases/      # tags stored here (as well)
  some-duplicated-tag
```

So the command for initialization was:

```sh
git svn init https://mycompany.com/svn/project \
  --trunk=trunk \
  --branches=dev-branches \
  --tags=branches \
  --tags=releases
```

This repo history is very long and convoluted, so there are duplicating tag names under `releases/` and `branches/` (illustrated above). But their history (log) is different.

The the fetching process of git-svn did stumble on some (but not all) these refs:

```
fatal: Invalid revision range 968311febed061cac3a0ee2cd767b97558963987..refs/remotes/repo-svn/tags/some-duplicated-tag
rev-list --pretty=raw --reverse 968311febed061cac3a0ee2cd767b97558963987..refs/remotes/repo-svn/tags/some-duplicated-tag --: command returned error: 128
```

I removed a revmap for that tag and fetch went on (by rebuilding the revmap and creating the Git ref):

```sh
rm .git/svn/refs/remotes/repo-svn/tags/some-duplicated-tag/.rev_map.${SVN_REPO_UUD}
```

After the checkout these refs only contain history from one of the sources (either from `releases/` or `tags/`). How do I preserve both?

Comment: Would it make sense to have the `branches` as Git branches, and the `releases` as Git tags?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Entries under `branches/` and `releases/` are both treated as tags, while real branches go under `dev-branches/`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to give unique prefixes to the tags. Since Git supports `refnames/like/this`. This is how I edited my `.git/config` after running `git svn init`:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    fetch = repo/trunk:refs/remotes/repo-svn/trunk
    branches = repo/dev-branches/*:refs/remotes/repo-svn/*
    tags = repo/releases/*:refs/remotes/repo-svn/tags/*
    tags = repo/branches/*:refs/remotes/repo-svn/tags/tag-branches/*
```